# Cannot resume from hibernate using systemd under Ubuntu15.10

Tags: suspend, hibernate, systemd, resume

I've having some issues with getting resume from hibernate using systemd (swsusp) to work on a Lenovo IdeaPad Z510, running under Ubuntu 15.10 (issue was the same under prior versions of Ubuntu as well).

- **DOES:** From a successfully-hibernated machine (journalctl confirms
  success), resume appears to generate a "dead screen" (black display,
  no apparent session or keyboard interaction, yet nothing in
  journalctl indicating display/session failure).
- **SHOULD:** From hibernate, restore session from swap partition and allow
  user to continue session.

As a clue, if I set nomodeset in grub, line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, resume works consistently well, though the native graphics hardware is clearly disabled (Haswell HD Mobile 4400).

Given this, I suspect two possible issues that would be causing this problem:

- On my machine, resume with an integrated video driver (Intel i915) is
  not yet properly configured.
- In my reading, I ran across a known kernel issue that relates to
  resume failure due to a memory size mismatch in the resume swap file.
  Referred to as the BIOS e820 mismatch, it's best described here:
  http://www.slideshare.net/joeylikernel/the-e820-trap-of-linux-kernel-hibernation.

In this later case, it sounds like the 4.3 kernel release may resolve at least this one possible reason for my resume issues.

But for now, I'm interested in better understanding the former case, as I want to check all of my assumptions as they relate to configuring systemd to successfully permit hibernate and resume.

To date, here's what I've done to configure my machine for hibernate/resume using systemd:

1. In etc/default/grub, configure GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to include
   the resume parameter, passing the UUID of the swap partition in
   question (i.e., resume=UUID=453f0121-505d-42d3-8dad-87f913e67ddc). My
   current GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT is
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
   resume=UUID=453f0121-505d-42d3-8dad-87f913e67ddc"
2. Run *sudo update-grub*
3. Edit/confirm resume=UUID=453f0121-505d-42d3-8dad-87f913e67ddc entry
   in resume file located in /etc/initramfs
4. Run *sudo update-initramfs -u*
5. Edit /etc/systemd/logind.conf to set HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
6. Run *sudo service systemd-logind restart*
7. Reboot for good measure

Resume will consistently fail with no obvious (to me) errors indicating the reason for the resume failure.

**So, my question to the forum is this:**

**What debugging tools, systemd information resources, and general understanding of how to troubleshoot what appears to be a video driver issue can you recommend?**

I'm quite interested in solving this situation within the context of using systemd as a solution.

Thanks very much.

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I never did receive a good answer to the question about how best to troubleshoot hibernate issues on my laptop, I **did** finally install kernel 4.8 (via a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10), and hibernate now does as expected.

Hope this helps folks with the same issues I had...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. The only solution I found at the time was updating the kernel. After update to 4.5.3-generic the problem was gone.

The how-to upgrade linux kernel is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade).

You can check your kernel version through terminal:

```
uname -r
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried these options

> acpi_osi=linux i915.enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1
>   i915.enable_fbc=1 pcie_aspm=force

and until now the problem seems to be gone

taken from this [link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=289685)

**EDIT:**

> acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'

now I'm using this option and until now it works as it should be

## EDIT

I'm not an expert but I have the same issue.
My last attempt ( and it appears to be working ), I had removed `acpi` `acpid` and `acpi_call` packages ..
I don't know if they are related to the problem .. but I am know using kernel 4.4.10 and the hibernation is working well.

Comment: @Baron... unfortunately this did not solve my immediate issue: I still demonstrate a failure to resume from hibernate with the switches  (as an aside, I was a bit suspect, as they are primarily for managing power and have little to do with suspend/hibernate/resume).

And, as noted by Pilot, I'm really interested in debugging tools for better understanding the context of my specific issue.